# Nested collection filter with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a collection like as below

```
var flights = [{
    id: 1,
    legs:[{
        carrierName:'Pegasus' 
    }]
}, {
    id: 2,
    legs:[{
        carrierName: 'SunExpress'
    },{
        carrierName: 'SunExpress'
    }]
}, {
    id: 3,
    legs:[{
        carrierName: 'Pegasus'
    },{
        carrierName: 'SunExpress'
    }]
}]
```

I want to filter it for example carrierName = 'Pegasus' then my result is like this

```
[{
    id: 1,
    legs:[{
        carrierName:'Pegasus' 
    }]
}, {
    id: 3,
    legs:[{
        carrierName: 'Pegasus'
    },{
        carrierName: 'SunExpress'
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just check if some legs of flight contains carrierName

```
_.filter(flights, function(flight) {
    return _.chain(flight)
        .get('legs')
        .map('carrierName')
        .includes('Pegasus')
        .value()
});
```

for check arr of values

```
_.filter(flights, function(flight) {
    return _.chain(flight)
        .get('legs')
        .map('carrierName')
        .thru(function(names) {
            return _.every(valuesArr, function(val) { // _.some for OR, _.every for AND
                return _.includes(names, val);
            });
        })
        .value()
});
```

Comment: it's worked well how can i make includes with array ex: ['Pegasus','SunExpress'] ?

Comment: @Mr.Ayanlar i update answer, valuesArr - ['Pegasus','SunExpress']

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check each sub array using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if it includes the search term:

```
var carrierNames = ['Pegasus', 'SunExpress'];

flights.filter(function(item) {
  var predicate = this; // the carrierNames dictionary

  return item.legs.some(function(leg) {
    return predicate[leg.carrierName]; // see if carrierName exists in the dictionary
  });
}, carrierNames.reduce(function(obj, term) { // create a dictionary of carrierNames
  obj[term] = true;
  return obj;
}, Object.create(null)));
```

```js
var flights = [{
    id: 1,
    legs:[{
        carrierName:'Pegasus' 
    }]
}, {
    id: 2,
    legs:[{
        carrierName: 'SunExpress'
    },{
        carrierName: 'SunExpress'
    }]
}, {
    id: 3,
    legs:[{
        carrierName: 'Pegasus'
    },{
        carrierName: 'SunExpress'
    }]
}];

var carrierNames = ['Pegasus', 'SunExpress'];

var result = flights.filter(function(item) {
  var predicate = this;
  
  return item.legs.some(function(leg) {
    return predicate[leg.carrierName];
  });
}, carrierNames.reduce(function(obj, term) {
  obj[term] = true;
  return obj;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

And the same logic using ES6 arrow functions and parameters [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const result = flights.filter(function({ legs }) {
  const predicate = this;
  return legs.some(({ carrierName }) => predicate.has(carrierName)); // keep if carrierName is in the Set
}, new Set(carrierNames)); // create a Set from the carrierNames
```

```js
const flights = [{
  id: 1,
  legs: [{
    carrierName: 'Pegasus'
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  legs: [{
    carrierName: 'SunExpress'
  }, {
    carrierName: 'SunExpress'
  }]
}, {
  id: 3,
  legs: [{
    carrierName: 'Pegasus'
  }, {
    carrierName: 'SunExpress'
  }]
}];

const carrierNames = ['Pegasus', 'SunExpress'];

const result = flights.filter(function({ legs }) {
  const predicate = this;
  return legs.some(({ carrierName }) => predicate.has(carrierName));
}, new Set(carrierNames));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: how can i make includes with array ex: ['Pegasus','SunExpress'] ?

Comment: Should it include all the terms in the array or just one of them? Are you using ES6?

Answer (score 0):

With ES6, you could use a single line for filtering, using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
var flights = [{ id: 1, legs: [{ carrierName: 'Pegasus' }] }, { id: 2, legs: [{ carrierName: 'SunExpress' }, { carrierName: 'SunExpress' }] }, { id: 3, legs: [{ carrierName: 'Pegasus' }, { carrierName: 'SunExpress' }] }],
    search = new Set(['Pegasus', 'SunExpress']);
    result = flights.filter(a => a.legs.some(b => search.has(b.carrierName)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i don't want ES6 for now. how can i make it using lodash?

Answer (score 0):

thank you everybody. I solved it with like as below

```
    var airlines = ["Pegasus",SunExpress"];
    var result = _.filter(flights, function(item) {
                        return _.some(item.legs, function(leg) {
                            return _.includes(airlines, leg.carrierName);
                        });
                    });
```